# Creating an artifact that the heroes must destroy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques, story, adventure-writing

I'm on a Lord of the Rings kick, so I'm curious how you'd create a major plot device that is both the main antagonist and the strongest weapon they have without killing the party with Ring Wraiths (or whatever monsters it would summon) due to their use.

Basically I want 3 things solved.

1. How to make it not just a number of will saves to be the only difference and point to its power.
2. making sure that they feel a need to move whilst not just killing them with wraiths
3. Making it that, whilst not making the journey annoying, that they can't just teleport to the end of the trek and have a quick dungeon crawl

Comment: To those who vote to close it, please tell me why

Comment: Your tagging suggests to me that you're looking for story ideas - this is a broad, opinion-based question with no objective criteria that can be used to rate answers. If you're looking for PF rules for artifacts, you would need to add some information about what you're actually trying to achieve in game terms.

Comment: oh... Sorry... I tossed in adventure writing because I thought "I'm asking about a plot device item, better put in adventure writing and story" Though I more mean how to handle such an artifact in mechanics

Comment: wait... I never put story. I put gm techniques

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend editing the tags - and adding some details about what you want the artifact to do and what consequences you want it to have on your game.

Comment: I added the story tag, since this sounds like story crafting and not a mere GM technique. Change the tags if you feel it is inaccurate.

Comment: I thought GM techniques because of not wanting the players to be swamped with encounters with ring monster things

Answer (score 6):

Some stories are not suited to some systems.

An antagonistic magical item will be modeled with the intelligent item rules. [These rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/intelligentItems.html#), as a relic of 3.5, are... pretty horrible. Let us call our artefact "The one ring."

It's a Lawful evil (or chaotic, or... whatever), ring which can cast a 4th level spell at will. That's more powerful than normal, but just fine for an artefact. It's got a purpose of "Defend the servants and interests of a specific deity" in the sense of "it would prefer to seduce the user to serve", See: gollum.

Total ego boost of +4 there.

Then there's:

> When a personality conflict occurs, the possessor must make a Will saving throw (DC = item's Ego). If the possessor succeeds, she is dominant. If she fails, the item is dominant. Dominance lasts for 1 day or until a critical situation occurs (such as a major battle, a serious threat to either the item or the character, and so on). Should an item gain dominance, it resists the character's desires and demands concessions
>   ...

Obviously, some tweaking for the seduction of evil will be necessary, but that's just fine for a plot artefact of middling-low power. This item will *also* have suggestion, 3/day, that it can use for its own purposes.

Thus, carrying the item is a series of tedious will saves that's best resolved with a quick teleport. Happily, the heroes of D&D are rather better equipped than lord of the rings and can neatly seal away this ring in an extra-dimensional space, shield the carrier via mind blank, and teleport to the final destination for a quick dungeon crawl, thereby saving many thousands of words of narrative.

Comment: Unless their powerful mentor figure is just a 5th level magic user, that is :P But agreed that it's not really a D&D appropriate adventure in many ways.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yqVD0swvWU

Comment: Also related: http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=612